# Linux Mint Debian - Change terminal title to servername

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, linux-mint

I am using the standard terminal and i want to change the terminal title after connecting via ssh to a other server.
Is there a possible way?

Thanks ya!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the terminal title?

Comment: And what is "standard terminal"?

Comment: I am using the GNOME-Terminal. With the terminal title i mean the text which is displayed when i open a new tab strg+shift+t

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however it can be tricky depending on which terminal emulator your using (and if it follows the standards) along with which shell your using.

You *could* set it directly from the prompt being set, in bash:

`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'` in your bash.rc will do the job.

You can have variables in this, so it'll be updated each time the prompt is returned.

Or you can execute a script manually, using just the echo command `echo -ne "\033]0;Server123\007"` which would set a static title for the terminal until you overwrite it again.

Comment: What should `echo -ne` return? I get no output

Comment: And i dont want to change the prompt.. I want to change the title of the terminal tab